# How to dynamic change the background color of div using color picker/color swatches using VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, colors, picker

Is it possible to dynamically change the background-color of the the class `.hasPicked`

I want to change the background-color by using the **input color picker** and **color swatches**.
I have the codes implemented in codepen.
Here: https://codepen.io/jcfloirendo01/pen/abpygdM

Answer (score 0):

Your Codepen binds `div.hasPicked`'s background color to `isFontColorSelected` (a color value):

```html
<div class="hasPicked" :style="{backgroundColor: isFontColorSelected}">
```

...but only the swatch selector is bound to `isFontColorSelected`. The color picker is bound to a different variable: `isFontColorPicked` (which seems otherwise unused).

```html
<input type="color" v-model="isFontColorPicked">
```

The fix is to bind the color picker to the same variable as the others:

```html
<input type="color" v-model="isFontColorSelected">
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RwKLqMR?editors=1010)